# Flutter listview builder starting index

Tags: flutter

I want to create a list with a specified index at the beginning, how about a case like this :

from start a list => List data = [1,2,3,4,5];
to new list newData = [3,4,5];

and how to make the index start from 2, in list newData!

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
List<int> newData = data.getRange(2, data.length).toList();
print("$newData");
//output : I/flutter (15236): [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `skip` method from list.

its more safe instead of `getRange`, because it will not throw error index range if the list are empty.

or you can also combine with `take()` mehtod.

```
  List a = [1,2,4,5,6,8,9];
  
  print(a.skip(3);// [5, 6, 8, 9]
  print(a.take(3)); // [1, 2, 4]
  print (a.skip(4).take(2)); // [6, 8]
  

  // this will not throw error index range
  print(a.skip(100)); // []
```